# How i can shift one row dataframe to be header?

Tags: r, dataframe, header, row, shift

Whats wrong in the input codes, where and why the numbers 5109 2 5 5.1 5.2 come to header, i want to id row at 4509 be the header.

> data[1:3,1:5]

```
         ID   X1  X2 X3 X4
1    02003KH1 -9  1  2  1
2 02003KH1005 -9  0  1  2
3 02003KH1021 -9  1  1  1

> data[4507:4509,1:5]
           ID    X1 X2 X3 X4
4507 2010XX2178  -9 0 2 2
4508 2010XX2228  -9 0 2 2
4509 id        G_r8 G_r9 G_r5 G_r80

> names(data) <- data[data$ID=='id',]

> data[1:3,1:5]
    5109       2 5 5.1 5.2
1 02003KH1    -9 1   2   1
2 02003KH1005 -9 0   1   2
3 02003KH1021 -9 1   1   1
```

Comment: Is this the same question you posted earlier?  I showed you a way to get the output

Comment: Yes, Thanx, But unfortunately, i didnt get advantage!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to remove the factor levels from your data frame see similar posts on the subject ([Convert data.frame columns from factors to characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters), [How to change factor labels into string in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204729/how-to-change-factor-labels-into-string-in-a-data-frame)). Here's a short example based on the supplied data for answering the question.

```
dat = data.frame(ID=c('0200','02003','020034','id','020039'),
           X1=c(-9,-9,-9,'G1',-9),
           X2=c(1,0,1,'G2',0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(dat) <- dat[dat$ID=='id',]) 
dat <- dat[which(dat$id!='id'),]  # remove the 'id' row
```

Comment: its Good, but i dont know whats wrong in my dataset, as you show i should set the id row to be header.
my id row in dataset is 4509 number of row.

    i did the names(data)<-data[4509,]
but instead the id row the some unusual numbers go to head
    5109  2  5  5.1   5.2
i dont know where these numbers come from!

Comment: Did you convert it to a character first? You'll need to remove the factor levels to get it to work. Try adding `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when you import the `data.frame`. You can also specify the number of the row (e.g. `names(dat) <- dat[32,]`).